# how to merge two siblings using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to merge two siblings

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td> table data</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td> table data</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Expected output:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td> table data</td>
</tr>
<tr><td> table data</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

My xslt code is :

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::tbody)">
         <tbody>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
         </tbody>
         </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
```

which is not giving the correct output. Could you please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example could be handled simply by:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/table">
    <xsl:copy>
        <tbody>
            <xsl:copy-of select="tbody/*"/>
        </tbody>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: but by using all the solutions mentioned above, I am not getting desired result.

Comment: *"I am not getting desired result."* But I am: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94rmq5X

Comment: Now its working fine for me also. Thanks for your help !

Comment: If I need to change <tr> tag into <row> and some other mapping with <td> tag then output will take only one change. like if tbody thing works then other mapping will not and vice versa

Comment: could you please suggest what should I do so that all mappings can done

Comment: Instead of `<xsl:copy-of select="tbody/*"/>` do `<xsl:apply-templates select="tbody/*"/>` and add templates matching `tr` and other elements you need to modify.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues with your current XSLT

1. Your template matches the document node, which in your case is the parent of the `table` element, not the `table` element itself. As you are trying to group on child `tbody` elements, your template should match the `table` element
2. `xsl:value-of` returns just the text value of a node. You should be using `xsl:copy-of` here (or `xsl:apply-templates` in conjunction with the identity template). You should also select all items in the group, not just the current item.
3. You haven't accounted for what happens for nodes under table other than `tbody`

So, your XSLT should look like this....

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="table">
    <table>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::tbody)">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
            <tbody>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/*"/>
            </tbody>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note, if you are using XSLT 3.0, you can replace the identity template with this:

```
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
```

On the other hand, if you are actually only to use XSLT 1.0, then you need to do [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). That means defining a key like so:

```
<xsl:key name="table" match="table/*" use="boolean(self::tbody)" />
```

Then, instead of using `xsl:for-each-group`, do this (although this will group all `tbody` elements, not just adjacent ones)

```
<xsl:for-each select="*[generate-id() = generate-id(key('table', boolean(self::tbody))[1])]">
```

Try this XSLT instead

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:key name="table" match="table/*" use="boolean(self::tbody)" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="table">
    <table>
      <xsl:for-each select="*[generate-id() = generate-id(key('table', boolean(self::tbody))[1])]">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="self::tbody">
            <tbody>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="key('table', true())/*"/>
            </tbody>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('table', false())" />
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Of course, after all this, Michael.Hor257k's answer is much simpler in this case. (Although it is definitely worth reading up on Muenchian Grouping if indeed you are stuck with XSLT 1.0).

Comment: I am using xalan. but current-grouping-key() is not supported for xalan. Could you please suggest is there any way to run this on xalan

Comment: gwtting this error while running using xalan                                                      SystemId Unknown; Line #75; Column #51; Could not find function: current-grouping-key
SystemId Unknown; Line #75; Column #51; function token not found.

Comment: @RichaBajaj If you're using Xalan, why do you have `xsl:for-each-group` in your question? Surely that produces an error too.

Comment: yes, for-each will also not supported to xalan. Now I have seen this.

Comment: is there any replacement of current-grouping-key() which will run successfully with xalan

Comment: I've made an edit to my answer to show it works in XSLT 1.0, although michael.hor257k's answer is much simpler in this particular case.